# Get real URL with file_get_contents

Tags: php, redirect, header, location, file-get-contents

I want to index a few websites so I can implement it's data into my own framework. Some websites use services like bit.ly to create smaller urls, which is very inconvenient. I would like to use file_get_contents to retrieve both the actual url as it's content.

How would I go about this?

Comment: http://zzz.rezo.net/HowTo-Expand-Short-URLs.html

Comment: don't use file_get_contents, because most of the servers are disable the file_get_contents, so you can use the CURL function

Answer (score 0):

Function by @Renaud

```
function get_web_page( $url ) {
    $res = array();
    $options = array( 
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,     // return web page 
        CURLOPT_HEADER         => false,    // do not return headers 
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,     // follow redirects 
        CURLOPT_USERAGENT      => "spider", // who am i 
        CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER    => true,     // set referer on redirect 
        CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 120,      // timeout on connect 
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 120,      // timeout on response 
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS      => 10,       // stop after 10 redirects 
    ); 
    $ch      = curl_init( $url ); 
    curl_setopt_array( $ch, $options ); 
    $content = curl_exec( $ch ); 
    $err     = curl_errno( $ch ); 
    $errmsg  = curl_error( $ch ); 
    $header  = curl_getinfo( $ch ); 
    curl_close( $ch ); 

    $res['content'] = $content;     
    $res['url'] = $header['url'];
    return $res; 
}  
print_r(get_web_page("http://google.com/"));
```